# Why doesn't a class have to provide a failable initializer if it implements a protocol that declares one?

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

I am trying to understand the following, *contrived*, example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  init?(string: String)
}

class MyObject: MyProtocol {
  let s: String
  required init(string: String) {
    self.s = string
  }
}

let o = MyObject(string: "test")
print(o.s)
```

`MyProtocol` declares a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID224). `MyObject` conforms to `MyProtocol` and the example code compiles and executes without issue.

My question is: Why doesn't `MyObject` ***have*** to provide a failable initializer (as per `MyProtocol`)?

Comment: The fallible initialiser is still an initialiser that returns a `MyObject` in the ideal case. It is trumped by the non-failiable initialiser of the same signature. You still have to provide the initialiser with the same signature for the code to compile. I guess it's a fallible initialiser that can't fail. In a way.

Comment: Perhaps because optionals are optional? Haha but on a more serious note an intialized object which is always `.Some` will satisfy your protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for the same reason that this compiles:

```
class A {
    init?(s:String) {}
    init() {}
}
class B : A {
    override init(s:String) {super.init()}
}
```

`init` can override (i.e. be substituted for) `init?`.

See also the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) (when something is so clearly documented, it seems silly to ask "why"; it's just a fact about the language):

> A failable initializer requirement can be satisfied by a failable or nonfailable initializer on a conforming type.

(As pointed out in the comments on the question and on the answer, this makes perfect sense if you think about the difference between an `init?` that happens never to fail and an `init` with the same signature — namely, there is *no* effective difference. To put it another way: You can tell me that I *may* fail, but you cannot tell me that I *must* fail.)

Comment: When you have an instance of B there *is* an implementation for init?(). That is not true in my case as MyObject doesn't provide an implementation for MyProtocol's failable initializer.

Comment: It's because an initializer that is failable needs to return a `nil` OR `non-nil` object. Since a nonfailable initializer always returns a `non-nil` object it satisfies his protocol and kind of just makes sense.

Comment: @NSGangster Very well put. @RobertJoseph, here's another way of seeing it: Imagine that you did implement `init?` but, as a matter of fact, your implementation _never_ returned `nil`. Clearly, _that_ would satisfy the requirement. Well, implementing `init` is the same as that.

Comment: +1 for finding it in the docs. For those looking its under the section titled `Failable Initializer Requirements`